# Are there different noun forms of 'complex' and 'complicated?'

Tags: single-word-requests, differences

There are [subtle differences](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/13445/2852) between *complex* and *complicated.*  As far as I can tell, though, they both merge into one noun form: *complexity.*

Merriam-Webster [has an entry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/complicatedness) for *complicatedness,* but that sounds outright contrived.

Are there any better words for this?

Comment: Another noun form is "complication".

Comment: There's also "complexification", this is used mainly by [mathematicians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification), but it also appears occasionally (and arguably mistakenly) in the [real world](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=complexification).

Comment: Are you asking for words based off of complex and complicated, or just synonyms?

Comment: @Mahnax Words based on complex and complicated, preferably.

Comment: Why was I downvoted?  I feel the question is pretty clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use *intricacy* (a measure of how *intricate* something is). Or even *convolution*, depending on the context. It would appear that the only other words based off of *complex* and *complicated* are *complexification* (which may or may not be a word), and *complication*.

Answer (score 0):

While complex is not a usually noun it can be a noun in special usage (e.g., Oedipus Complex). It's mainly an adjective. The common noun is complexity and for complicated the common noun is complication. However a major poet, Wallace Stevens, uses complicate as noun ("the complicate" in "Notes Toward a Supreme Fiction," part three, section VI), indicating the flexibility of English to go beyond convention.

Comment: All residents in my apartment complex and all workers in my office complex disagree.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, complex is not a noun. It is an adjective. The noun is complexity and for complicated the noun in complication.

Comment: _Complication_ is not usually just the nominal counterpart to adjectival _complicated_. Its basic meaning is “a circumstance that complicates something; a difficulty” ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/complication)), rather than just “the state of being complicated”.

Comment: (1) First of all, _complex_ ***is*** a noun in some contexts. (2) The question isn't suggesting that _complex_ is a noun. It is saying "_complex_ and _complicated_ are adjectives that are similar but not interchangeable. The word _complexity_ clearly represents the state or quality of being _complex_. Is there a distinct noun corresponding to _complicated_, or do you use _complexity_ for it, too?" (3) +1 What Janus said.

Answer (score -1):

"Complex" can be used as a noun. From Dictionary.com:

"noun. an intricate or complicated association or assemblage of related things, parts, units, etc.: the entire complex of our educational system; an apartment complex."

As an adjective, "complex" is synonymous with "intricate."